# Sort list into sublists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a program that sorts a list and then groups each portion of the list that is sorted into separate lists and output it into a list of lists. Here's a check that should make it more clear:

```
> (sort-lists > '())
empty

> (sort-lists < '(1 2 3))
(list (list 1 2 3))

> (sort-lists >= '(2 2 2 2))
(list (list 2 2 2 2))

> (sort-lists < '(5 4 3 2 1))
(list (list 5) (list 4) (list 3) (list 2) (list 1))

> (sort-lists < '(1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 9 8 7))
(list
 (list 1 2 3 4)
 (list 2 3 4 5 6)
 (list 1 2 9)
 (list 8)
 (list 7))
```

Here's what I have:

```
(define (sort-lists rel? ls)
  (cond
    [(empty? ls) '()]
    [(rel? (first ls) (first (rest ls)))
     (list (cons (first ls) (sort-lists rel? (rest ls))))]
    [else (cons (first ls) (sort-lists rel? (rest (rest ls))))]))
```

I'm having a problem with the (first (rest ls)) part because if there is no first of rest then it gives an error, same with rest of rest.

Also this has to be a *single pass function without any helpers* in ISL+. Any help would be great.

Is there a way to use local to merge the solution to the recursive subproblem to an ans variable, and then complete the answer. So for `(sort-lists < '(1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 9 8 7))`, you would define ans be the result of running `(sort-lists < '(2 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 9 8 7))`, which is `'((2 3 4) (2 3 4 5 6) (1 2 9) (8) (7)).`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't really call this a *sort* so much as some type of partitioning. You're trying to collect the longest contiguous sequences of elements that are already sorted according to the predicate.  I know you said that you have to bundle this all into one function, but it's probably much easier to *first* write it as separate functions, and then combine them into one.

In tackling this problem, it's probably helpful to break it down into subtasks.  First, at the highest level, when the list comes in, there's some initial prefix of ascending elements, and then there's the rest of the elements after that.  The result should be a list of that first prefix and then the result of processing the rest of the elements. That gives us a structure like this:

```
(define (slice predicate lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      ;; If lst is empty, then there no contiguous 
      ;; subsequences within it, so we return '() 
      ;; immediately.
      '()
      ;; Otherwise, there are elements in lst, and we 
      ;; know that there is definitely a prefix and
      ;; a tail, although the tail may be empty. Then
      ;; the result is a list containing the prefix,
      ;; and whatever the sliced rest of the list is.
      (let* ((prefix/tail (ordered-prefix predicate lst))
             (prefix (first prefix/tail))
             (tail (second prefix/tail)))
        (list* prefix (slice predicate tail)))))
```

I hope the logic in that function is relatively clear.  The only bits that might be a bit unusual are the **let***, which performs sequential bindings, and **list**, which the same as **cons**.  There's also a reference to a function, **ordered-prefix**, that we haven't defined yet.  Its task is to return a list of two values; the first is the ordered prefix of the list, and the second is the tail of the list after that prefix.  Now we just need to write that function:

```
(define (ordered-prefix predicate lst)
  (cond
    ;; If the list is empty, then there's no prefix,
    ;; and the tail is empty too.
    ((empty? lst)
     '(() ()))
    ;; If the list has only one element (its `rest` is
    ;; empty, then the prefix is just that element, and 
    ;; the tail is empty.
    ((empty? (rest lst))
     (list (list (first lst)) '()))
    ;; Otherwise, there are at least two elements, and the
    ;; list looks like (x y zs...).
    (else 
     (let ((x (first lst))
           (y (second lst))
           (zs (rest (rest lst))))
       (cond
         ;; If x is not less than y, then the prefix is (x),
         ;; and the tail is (y zs...).
         ((not (predicate x y))
          (list (list x) (list* y zs)))
         ;; If x is less than y, then x is in the prefix, and the 
         ;; rest of the prefix is the prefix of (y zs...).  
         (else 
          (let* ((prefix/tail (ordered-prefix predicate (list* y zs)))
                 (prefix (first prefix/tail))
                 (tail (second prefix/tail)))
            (list (list* x prefix) tail))))))))
```

Now, this is enough to make **slice** work:

```
(slice < '())                ;=> ()
(slice < '(1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5)) ;=> ((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5))
```

It's not all in one function, though.  To get it there, you'll need to get the definition of **ordered-prefix** into the definition of **slice**.  You can use **let** to bind functions within other functions, like:

```
(define (repeat-reverse lst)
  (let ((repeat (lambda (x)
                  (list x x))))
    (repeat (reverse lst))))
```

```
(repeat-reverse '(1 2 3)) ;=> ((3 2 1) (3 2 1))
```

However, that won't work for **ordered-prefix**, since **ordered-prefix** is recursive;  it needs to be able to refer to itself.  You can do that with **letrec** though, which allows functions to refer to themselves. E.g.:

```
(define (repeat-n-reverse lst n)
  (letrec ((repeat-n (lambda (x n)
                       (if (= n 0) 
                           '()
                           (list* x (repeat-n x (- n 1)))))))
    (repeat-n (reverse lst) n)))
```

```
(repeat-n-reverse '(1 2 3) 3)     ;=> ((3 2 1) (3 2 1) (3 2 1))
(repeat-n-reverse '(x y) 2)       ;=> ((y x) (y x))
(repeat-n-reverse '(a b c d e) 0) ;=> ()
```

OK, so now we're ready to put it all together. (Since **ordered-prefix** is now defined *within* **slice**, it will already have access to the predicate, and we can remove it from the argument list, but still use it.)

```
(define (slice predicate lst)
  (letrec ((ordered-prefix
            (lambda (lst)
              (cond
                ((empty? lst)
                 '(() ()))
                ((empty? (rest lst))
                 (list (list (first lst)) '()))
                (else 
                 (let ((x (first lst))
                       (y (second lst))
                       (zs (rest (rest lst))))
                   (cond
                     ((not (predicate x y))
                      (list (list x) (list* y zs)))
                     (else 
                      (let* ((prefix/tail (ordered-prefix (list* y zs)))
                             (prefix (first prefix/tail))
                             (tail (second prefix/tail)))
                        (list (list* x prefix) tail))))))))))
    (if (empty? lst)
        '()
        (let* ((prefix/tail (ordered-prefix lst))
               (prefix (first prefix/tail))
               (tail (second prefix/tail)))
          (list* prefix (slice predicate tail))))))
```

This is relatively efficient, too.  It doesn't allocate any unnecessary data, except for the places where I used **(list* y zs)** for clarity, where that's the same value as **(rest lst)**.   You should probably change that, but I wanted to leave it as is for clarity.

The only performance consideration is that this is not *tail recursive*, so you use a lot more stack space.  To get around that, you'd need to convert the recursion to a form that builds up the list in reverse, and then reverses it when its time to return it.  That's what I was doing in the original (you can still view the edit history), but it's probably overkill for what appears to be an academic exercise.

Comment: I'm looking over this, but most of it doesn't make sense. We haven't done letrec, loop or let. I looked up letrec and let and they seem like the local and lambda function, but you have a letrec within a letrec and "^"prefix which doesn't make to much sense. Is there a way too simply the language?

Comment: @Ryan Actually, I cleaned up some of the code.  `letrec` is like let, except that the variables that it binds are in scope of the other bindings.  E.g., you can do `(letrec ((p (lambda (n) (p n)))) (p 10))` would be an infinite loop because `p` is bound to a function that calls `p` (which is itself).  `loop` isn't anything special;  it's just another variable bound to a function.  I just used the name `loop` because it's a recursive function that's essentially performing a loop.  The `^` on a variable doesn't do anything either;  I was just using it to indicate that the value actually needed

Comment: @Ryan to be reversed before returning it.  In many list processing exercises, it's easier to build the result in reverse order and then reverse it when returning it.  So in building up (1 2 3) from (1 2 3 1), we'd be incrementally building the prefix/tail combinations ()/(1 2 3 1), then (1)/(2 3 1), then (2 1)/(3 1), then (3 2 1)/(1), and then we reverse the prefix to return (1 2 3)/(1).

Comment: Okay. I still don't understand the letrec in reguards to how it would look converted to local, but I noticed you used reverse and it looks like other such functions which go through the list multiple times as opposed to in a single pass which is the main part. It's good code, but it would take too long on long lists because of all the passes with reverse and other functions.

Comment: Reverse is never being called with the main list, and this makes just one pass through the main list. Unless you can use set! And set-car! And set-cdr!, i think most solutions are going to either build results in reverse, or copy a lot of intermediate data.

Comment: That said, i think this can be simplified a bit

Comment: @Ryan OK, I pretty much completely reworked the answer.  It doesn't do anything with reverse anymore, and everything is based on building up the answer recursively.  There's still a use of letrec, but I've added some very simple examples to explain what letrec is used for.  I hope that this will be an informative. :)

Comment: I went through it and converted everything to local and lambda's and this looks perfect! Thank you so much! And your explanation is great!

Answer (score 1):

You want to break a list up into longest ascending sequences of numbers. And to do it in ISL+, *in one pass*.

This does it in a logic-programming pseudocode (well, Prolog):

```erlang
runs([],  [[] ]).
runs([A], [[A]]).
runs([A,B|C], R) :- 
   (   A > B   ->  runs([B|C],  S  ), R=[[A  ]|S]   
   ;   true    ->  runs([B|C],[D|S]), R=[[A|D]|S]   ).
```

This does the same in a Scheme-like pseudocode (well, full Racket):

```lisp
(define (runs xs)
   (match xs 
     ((list )  '(()))
     ((list A)  (list (list A)))
     ((list A B C ...)
        (cond
          ((> A B)
             (let ([S (runs (cons B C))])
                (cons (list A) S)))
          (else
             (let ([d_s (runs (cons B C))])
                (let ([D (car d_s)]
                      [S (cdr d_s)])
                   (cons (cons A D) S))))))))
```

All that's left for you to do is to fit this into the ISL+ language. I don't know what + stands for, but there's bound to be a `lambda` construct allowed in the "intermediate student with lambda" language. This lets us emulate the staged assignment of the nested `let`s as

```
          ( (lambda (d_s)
               ( (lambda (D S)
                     (cons (cons A D) S))
                 (car d_s)
                 (cdr d_s)))
            (runs (cons B C)))
```